# LWC Error on Mobile (only works desktop)Error during LWC component connect phase undefined is not an object evaluating n.length

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobile

I get this error message on mobile. The same exact component works in desktop and in the outlook for salesforce side application. I put the error and the code below.

This is in an quick action on the Account Record page. It is also accessible in a flow.

Thanks for all assistance!

[image]

```
<template>

<div class="slds-m-around_large">
    <p if:true={isLoaded}></p>
     <div if:false={isLoaded} class="slds-is-relative">
        <lightning-spinner
            size="medium"
            alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand">
        </lightning-spinner>
    </div>
</div>
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-combobox
        name="progress"
        label="Service Group"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Select Progress"
        options={options}
        onchange={handleChangeGroup} 
        required="true"></lightning-combobox>
        <br/>
        <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Please cc me on all email" checked={ccuser} onchange={handleCCMeChange}> </lightning-input>
    <br/>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Subject of Ticket" onchange={handleChangeSubject}
    required="true" class="validate" value={subject}>
    </lightning-input>

    <lightning-input type="text" label="Name"  onchange={handleChangeName}
    required="true" class="validate" value={name}>
        </lightning-input>
    <lightning-input type="email" label="Email address" onchange={handleChangeEmail}
    required="true" class="validate" value={email}>
        </lightning-input>

        <br/>
    {richTxtLabel}
    <lightning-input-rich-text value={description} blur={handleChangeDescription} onchange={handleChangeDescription}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>

   <!--  <c-file-upload-improved label={fileUploadLabel}>
    </c-file-upload-improved> -->
    <div slot="footer" class="slds-clearfix">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit"
         class="slds-var-m-left_x-small slds-float_right"
          onclick={handleSubmission}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

```
enter code hereimport {LightningElement,api,track} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getTicket } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getObjectInfo,getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import freshdeskObj from '@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c';
import fdsources from 
'@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c.FD_Group__c';
import NAME_FIELD from 
'@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c.Name';
import TICKET_FIELD from 
'@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c.freshdesk__ticketid__c';
 import ACCTID from '@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c.freshdesk__SalesforceAccount__c';
 import DESCRIPTION from 
'@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c.Ticket_RTF_Description__c';
 import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/freshdesk__Freshdesk_Ticket_Object__c.Id';
import {
FlowAttributeChangeEvent,
FlowNavigationNextEvent,
FlowNavigationFinishEvent,
} from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import createTicket from '@salesforce/apex/createFreshDeskTicket.createTicket';
import updateDescriptionImages from  '@salesforce/apex/createFreshDeskTicket.updateTicket';

export default class CreateFreshDeskTicket extends LightningElement {
@api richTxtLabel;  
@api description;
@api account;
@api accountId;
@api subject;
@api name;
@api email;
@api fileUploadLabel;  
@api multipleFiles; 
@api isLoaded;
@api calloutError;
@api outlook;
@api refreshcmp;
@api groups;
@api csgroup;
@api ccuser;
@api freshdeskId;

/* Removing wire due to the need to do dml in apex and cannot cache or use wire in this use case
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: freshdeskObj }) objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', // Default record type Id
    fieldApiName: fdsources
})


getPicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log('pikclist values');
        console.log(data.values);
      // Map picklist values to buttons
      this.groups = data.values.map(plValue => {
        return {
          label: plValue.label,
          value: plValue.value
        };
      });
    } else if (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  }
  */

  get options() {
    return [
        { label: 'Customer Service', value: 'Customer Service' },
        { label: 'Technical Support', value: 'Technical Support' },
        { label: 'Field Solutions', value: 'Field Solutions' },
    ];
}
connectedCallback() {
    this.ccuser = false;
    this.isLoaded = true;
    console.log('subject '+this.subject);
    this.calloutError = false;
    //console.log('from emaiil '+$people.from.email);
    //this.value = 'Customer Service';
    //this.csgroup = 'Customer Service';
    
  }
handleChangeSubject(event) {
    this.subject = event.target.value;
    
}
handleChangeEmail(event) {
    this.email = event.target.value;
    
}
handleChangeName(event) {
    this.name = event.target.value;
    
}
handleCCMeChange(event){
    this.ccuser = event.target.checked;
    console.log(' checkbox cc '+this.ccuser);
}
handleChangeGroup(event){
    this.csgroup = event.target.value;
    console.log('pick value '+this.csgroup);
}
handleChangeDescription(event) {
    this.description = event.target.value; 
    //console.log( event.target.value);     
}
showNotification() {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: this._title,
        message: this.message,
        variant: this.variant,
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    
}
handleSubmission(event){
    this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
    if(!this.accountId){
        this.variant = 'error';
        this.message = 'Please add an Account';
        this._title = 'Please add a Account';
        this.showNotification();
        this.isLoaded = true;
        return;
    }
    var desc = this.description;
    if(!desc){
        this.variant = 'error';
        this.message = 'Please add a description';
        this._title = 'Please add a description';
        this.showNotification();
        this.isLoaded = true;
        return;
        
    }else if(desc.includes('"')){
        console.log('quotes exist in desc');
        
    }else{
        console.log('not null but no quotes');
    }
    // update description and if successfull create ticket
    




    const isInputsCorrect = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
        .reduce((validSoFar, inputField) => {
            inputField.reportValidity();
            return validSoFar && inputField.checkValidity();
        }, true);

    const isPicklistCorrect = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox')]
    .reduce((validSoFar, inputField) => {
        inputField.reportValidity();
        return validSoFar && inputField.checkValidity();
    }, true);

    if (isInputsCorrect && isPicklistCorrect) {
     console.log('validation passed !');
     updateDescriptionImages({ description : this.description })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('here is updated description ');
        console.log(result);
        var desc = result.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
        console.log(desc);
        console.log(this.description);
        createTicket({ email : this.email , name : this.name
            , subject : this.subject
            , description : desc, acctId : this.accountId, fdgroup : this.csgroup , addemails : this.ccuser})
            
            .then(result => {
                this.isLoaded = true;
                debugger;
                if(result != 'Error'){
                        console.log('successfully created ticket with no error on the callback code');
                        console.log('result ');
                        console.log(result);
                        //console.log('stringified');
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                        try{
                            var parsed = JSON.parse(result);
                            //console.log(parsed.id);                            
                            
                        }catch(e){
                            console.log('there was an error updating FD Ticket');
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                        this.variant = 'success';
                        this.message = 'The ticket has been created and will be viewable in the Salesforce Freshdesk app in 24 hours';
                        this._title = 'Congrats, the ticket was sent to Customer Service';
                        this.showNotification();
                        console.log('outlok panel '+this.outlook);
                        if(this.outlook || this.outlook == "true"){
                            console.log('reloading outlook panel');
                            const value = Math.random()*1035;
                            const valueChangeEvent = new CustomEvent("valuechange", {
                            detail: { value }
                            });
                            // Fire the custom event
                            this.dispatchEvent(valueChangeEvent);
                                                        
                        }else{
                            console.log('finishing flow');
                            const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
                            this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);   
                           
                        }

                }else{
                    console.log('error none 201 code');
                    this.variant = 'error';
                    this.calloutError = true;
                    this.message = 'Sorry, we got an error when creating this ticket.';
                    this._title = 'Sorry there was an error. Please notify Admin of the error';
                    this.showNotification();

                }
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.isLoaded = true;
                //console.log(error);
                console.log('error on the callback catch line 139' );
                const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
                //this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
                this.variant = 'error';
                this.calloutError = true;
                this.message = 'Sorry, we got an error when creating this ticket.';
                this._title = 'Sorry there was an error. Please notify Admin of the error';
                this.showNotification();
            });
    })

    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error in updating description links ');
        console.log(error);
        this.isLoaded = true;
        const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
        //this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
        this.variant = 'error';
        this.calloutError = true;
        this.message = 'Sorry, we got an error when creating this ticket. Please let admin know there was an error in updating descriptions links';
        this._title = 'Sorry there was an error. Please notify Admin of the error';
        this.showNotification();

    })

    }else{
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error message except in the file name and component descriptor despite calling completely different code.
I solved it by adding the offending page to the Mobile Navigation Menu in the Page Activation wizard of the Lightning App Builder.